# Selenium Python how to run an XPath error handling exception on interval every 10 seconds?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

I'm new and have an issue with a project I'm doing.. I'm trying to let my code especially the error handling part run on interval every 10 maybe 30 seconds to see if the xpath is still being detected and if it is detected i want it to do nothing but if its not detected I would like it to run an exception although I'm having an issue figuring out how to do that, can anyone help?

New Code.

```
def code():
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                              options=options)

    driver.get("example.com")
    driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
    driver.set_window_size(750, 512)

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/button/span")
        print("success")
    except NoSuchElementException:  # spelling error making this code not work as expected
        pyautogui.moveTo(89, 56)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click()
        print("Error but moved to refresh")
        pass


schedule.every().day.at("19:37").do(code)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want the code to run the selenium browser window once a day and stay up on a loop, but i want the error handling part to run every 10 seconds to make sure the XPath is still there and if it isn't then run an exception.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you want to refresh the page if the element is not found.

Some suggestions:

1. Instead of `try-except`, use `.find_elements()` and verify the list is not empty. Exceptions, while necessary in some cases, are not needed here. Exceptions slow down your code.
2. I've coded this to run forever... no timeout. This is generally not a good idea but it's what you asked for. I would instead suggest you remove the loop and 10s sleep and just schedule this script to run every minute or whatever and do whatever you need it to do.
3. Instead of using `pyautogui` to click the refresh button, it's better just to use `driver.refresh` that's provided by Selenium. (If I'm understanding what you are doing correctly).
4. To have this repeat, you need a loop, `while True:`, and a pause between loops, `time.sleep(10)` for a 10s pause.
5. I know you are new but the locator you are using is not very good.  It's very brittle meaning it's very likely to break or find the wrong element because it starts at `/html`, is very long (many levels), and uses indices (e.g. `/div[2]`). I can't help fix it without either the relevant HTML (as text, properly formatted) in your question or a link to the page.

Summary:
The code uses `.find_elements()` to get the collection of elements that you are looking for, checks to see if the list is empty and if it is, refreshes the page. It then waits 10s and repeats indefinitely.

To do that cleanly, I would use the code below.

```
while True: 
    e = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/button/span")
    if not e:
        print("Element not found")
        # driver.refresh or whatever you want to run when the element isn't found

    time.sleep(10) # this is measured in seconds
```

Comment: Although this is already running in a While loop due to the schedule library, I want the code to run the selenium browser window once a day and stay up on a loop, but i want the error handling part to run every 10 seconds to make sure the XPath is still there and if it isn't then run an exception.

Comment: @D3AD_SHOT Understood. The code I provided should work... you just need to change the 30s wait to 10. I've updated the code and my answer to use 10s. The "exception" code you are looking for is inside the `if not e:` section. Just add whatever you want to run when the element doesn't exist there. I've added a comment in the section where the "element not found" section is so that you can update it with whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you are an absolute legend

Comment: Works perfectly, also did delete my second post it was in another tab thanks

Comment: @ JeffC do you by chance know how I'd be able to run multiple functions? Like more then one "def code():" with the method you explained?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you mean. It would be best to accept this answer for this question and then post a new question with all the details describing what you are trying to do and either I or someone else can help with the new question.